# Implementing Image collage to a 'Word' shape using HTML5/JS

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I would like to implement an image collage, where the photos are arranged on the page within a 'Word' object.

This is really hard to explain, this maybe why I haven't found any examples on the web. But as an example, let's take the word 'HTML'.

I would like to create a shape on a canvas on the screen, and then have photos transition onto the screen (easing, sliding, flying) and then arranging themselves sporadically around that shape. Then have the images clickable/zoomable. If possible, draggable as well within the shape.

Now, my first question, is this achievable, and how would I go about doing something like this?

I don't know too much surrounding HTML5 canvas, and am using this project to get my teeth into it. So I would really like to know briefly how something like this could be done.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like a mask in photoshop you would get an image with invisible area with the shape you want to mark and then put the world image in the background.

This might also be of help http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/